# Meaning of noun + のくらい in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-くらい

> 教室はたった一つでしたが生徒は三年生がないだけで、あとは一年から六年までみんな**ありました**。
>   It was a single classroom but, with the exception of third year students, it had everyone from year one to year six.
>   **運動場もテニスコートのくらいでした**が、すぐうしろは栗の木のあるきれいな草の山でしたし...
>   ??? but right behind it were beautiful grassy mountains with chestnut trees and ...

I'm struggling with the 運動場もテニスコートのくらいでした part. My guess is that it's saying that the classroom also acted as a tennis court and sports ground, but I can't convince myself 100%.

Also I don't think I've ever seen くらい with の before. Can I omit の without consequence?

**Edit:** The part I missed out is

> ...でしたし、運動場のすみにはごぼごぼつめたい水を噴く岩穴もあったのです。
>   ...and in the corner of the sports ground there was a cave where cool water bubbled out.

So I suppose this makes my guess completely wrong. Now I'm very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means that the sports ground was the same size as a tennis court.

Generally, we say it like 運動場もテニスコートぐらいでした.

I am not sure if it is typo or on purpose, but you know, Miyazawa Kenji has a very unique writing style. The grammar is not important for him.

Comment: "Grammar is not important for him" -- you make me worry about whether I should continue to read this book. Am I just going to get confused all the time?

Comment: @user3856370  I like Miyazawa Kenji, and his works are great. I don't mean his grammer is quite strange, but I think his works are difficult for non-native Japanese because he often used Touhoku dialect and  strange way of saying, though these are attraction of his works. You should not mind the correctness of grammar when you read his works.